# Which tense should be used and why?

Tags: grammar

> - Those of you who ***survive/will survive*** will be jealous of the dead.

I don't know why, but I have a little trouble with choosing. Could someone explain it to me?

Comment: If there's a choice between using a modal and not using a modal, and the meaning's the same, don't use the modal.

Comment: "Those of you who survive" sounds better to me, because survival is something you do both now and in the future, although both are grammatical. Certainly if you're talking to/about people alive now. An exception might be if you're talking about unborn children, who can't survive at the moment but may survive in the future. It's also common to say "Only some of you will survive", meaning some will die, emphasising the futurity, but that's a different structure than "who survive".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are possible, and there is hardly any difference in meaning. It follows that if you choose to use the modal *will*, you are choosing to put some emphasis on the futurity; but note that the futuruty is already implicitly there because of the *will* in the main clause.